# how to check the value coming from one foreach with another to check certain condition to display data

Tags: php

Two mysql query data are looped to display the data in php
First foreach loop:

```
foreach($data as $a){

}
```

Second foreach loop:

```
    foreach($data1 as $b){

}
```

currently using:

```
 foreach($data as $a){
      foreach($data1 as $b){
        if($a->catid == $b->catid && $a->userid == $b->userid){
           echo $b->catname;
        }

     }

}
```

Here i need to check if category and customer id coming from loop1 id present in loop2 if yes then display those data.
Problem is if i use nested foreach then loop2 execution completes first then loop1.

I want to display data coming from loop1 and if condition matches between loop1 and loop2 then display the data. Any alternate method for this ? Kindly suggest if any

Comment: Perhaps I'm confused on your question, but can you not just store the data you found in loop 1 in a couple of variables then check those variables in loop 2?

Comment: @MrB Sorry on for confusing. Purpose of loop1 is to display data in table. For one value i need to check the condition weather that id is matched with the data i get from loop2. But if i use like this loop2 will display all data first but not loop1

Comment: Can you provide more code? The 2 empty foreach loops don't help explain much.

Comment: It looks like this should work fine. Can't you display the data from the first loop, then go through the second loop and display more data if needed?

Or, you can loop through the first loop first and display the whole thing. Then, loop through the first loop again, plus the second, to see if you need to display any more.

There are more efficient ways to handle this, but that should work.

Comment: @Webkudu No its not working, i need loop as i am joining different tables in query to get the data and loop2 to another query values.
Now i need to check if id from loop1 is present in loop2 single value than display the name. 
but here its it check whole loop2 and display 2 name due to loops

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$catNames = array();
foreach($data as $a) {
  display($a);
  foreach($data1 as $b){
    if($a->catid == $b->catid && $a->userid == $b->userid){
       $catNames[] = $b->catname;
    }
  }
}
foreach($catNames as $catName) {
    echo $catName;
}
```